# EIP 1822 - Potential vulnerabilities in a proxiable contract example

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts, eip

I'm reading EIP-1822 UUPS. There's a reference, or sample, implementation of a proxy contract pattern for an ERC20 token contract, and I have some concerns about potential vulnerabilities. Here's the relevant code:

```
// Contracts...

contract MyToken is ERC20DataLayout, ERC20, Owned, Proxiable, LibraryLock {
    function constructor1(uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
        tokens[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        initialize();
        setOwner(msg.sender);
    }

    function updateCode(address newCode) public onlyOwner delegatedOnly {
        updateCodeAddress(newCode);
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public delegatedOnly {
        ERC20.transfer(to, amount);
    }
}
```

I assume the `MyToken` contract is deployed at some address e.g. `0x123`, and then the `Proxy` contract is deployed at some other address e.g. `0xabc`. The `Proxy` contract's constructor invokes the `constructor1` function of `MyToken` at `0x123`.

My concerns are:

1. **Direct Interaction with `MyToken`**: There seems to be no mechanism in place to prevent a user from directly interacting with the `MyToken` contract at address `0x123`. This could potentially allow an attacker to call the `constructor1` function and create an unauthorized instance of the token contract with its own `totalSupply` and `tokens` mapping. Maybe.
2. **Independent Storage**: If a user directly interacts with the `MyToken` contract at `0x123`, it would modify the storage variables of that contract instance independently from the instance created through the `Proxy` contract at `0xabc`. Does this create any security risks or potential for confusion?
3. **Function Accessibility**: The `constructor1` function appears to be a normal callable function after deployment, even though it is intended to be called only during the initial deployment process. Should there be additional access control measures in place to prevent unauthorized calls to this function?

My main concern is whether the provided implementation adequately protects against unauthorized interactions with the underlying `MyToken` contract, and if there are any potential vulnerabilities or risks that should be addressed.

I understand the state at 0x123 is not the same as the state at 0xabc, but it's still odd.

Bonus question: does it matter if the order of inheritance is altered in a version 2? Would that reorder the declaration of the variables and mess up the storage?

**Note** - I am learning and have not written a line of Solidity, yet. Due to the nature of this beast, I feel I need a very thorough understanding before I make a start. My point being that I expect I'm misunderstanding something here.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1822#erc-20-token